# How to generate sitemap with react router

Tags: reactjs, server-side, react-router, react-router-component

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically generate sitemap in reactJS server side (express) web app. I'm using react router.

Comment: How detailed do you need your sitemap to be? And I assume XML is fine?

Answer (score 15):

For simple ReactJS sitemap integration with React Router, you should check out the [react-router-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-sitemap) package.

It's fairly configurable as well, as you can see in the [docs](https://github.com/kuflash/react-router-sitemap/blob/master/api.md), so if you need to include change frequency or things like that, you should be able to do it no problem.

Or were you looking for a way to implement one yourself?

Comment: Does sitemap.xml created with react-router match our react-router-dom paths in router?Please answer anyone.

Comment: React Router Sitemap has not been updated in over 5 years, doesn't work with latest react version

Answer (score 7):

If your site frequently changes, you need to dynamically create the sitemap. I was stuck here and found this effective solution, which can even generate a real time sitemap by calling API for my website in ReactJS, using NextJs. [dynamic Sitemap Steps](https://leerob.io/blog/nextjs-sitemap-robots)

You can do this by creating most of the public files like

1. sitemap.xml
2. rss.feed
3. robots.txt
4. humans.txt

That too with preserving the behaviour of ReactJS.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used the code of this blog in my project. It helped me a lot.