# How to create a site map for a website in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react I have created a website but now i want to create a site map like this(captured from other website). I think it has to be done through react-router but still i am not sure and i don't know how to do that with react-router.

[image]

I have a router component somewhat like this

```
<Route path="/" component={LoginBox}/>
<Route path="/product" component={ProductLanding}/>
<Route path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard}/>
<Route path="/salesfunnel" component={Salesfunnel}/>
<Route path="/addmeeting" component={AddMeeting}/>
<Route path="/pitchProduct" component={PitchProduct}/>
<Route path="/mysubs" component={MySubs}/>
<Route path="/updateproduct" component={UpdateProduct}/>
<Route path="/transactionform" component={AddTransaction}/>
<Route path="/sellerLanding" component={SellerLanding}/>
<Route path="/addSeller" component={AddSeller}/>
```

Please do tell me how do i do this thing in react..
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, is showing the breadcrumbs what you want? If that's the case you can use [React Breadcrumbs](https://github.com/svenanders/react-breadcrumbs)

Comment: @CésarLandesa No i just want to use sitemap in my website.How do i use sitemap like that(in the question's example) in my website with the following routes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021438/how-to-generate-sitemap-with-react-router

Comment: @paqash Did not find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```js
<Route path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/cars" component={CarList}/>
<Route path="/cars/:id" component={CarDetail}/>
```

The Mumbai part, other filters you may apply to your listing such as location should be handled by the CarList component I think

Comment: Yeah that will be handled in the carList component but how do i add this to my page?

Comment: You want me to code your full CarList component? :P

Comment: No buddy :P i just want to know how do i create a site map based on these routes