# Generate sitemap in ReactJS, not working currently available solution

Tags: reactjs, sitemap, react-router-dom

I am working on reactjs application. I have created router using react-router-dom for same. It is a dynamic ecommerce website, so url needed for same in mentioned in router file.
I am new to reactjs, i need to create the sitemap xml file for seo purpose.

I tried the solution [How to generate sitemap with react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021438/how-to-generate-sitemap-with-react-router) but it is not helping me with creating sitemap as 2nd step mentioned in link http://botmap.io/ is not working. So i am stuck.